# Make imports local in imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

So this may sound weird to you. Say I have two files, `module.py` and `script.py`.

Here is what they may look like:

**module.py**

```
import time
print(time.time())
```

**script.py**

```
from module import *
time.sleep(0.1)  # Still works as time is imported in the module imported
```

How can I avoid this from happening?

If there is a duplicate question like this, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest answer is to avoid using `from module import *`.  It really isn't worth it anywhere other than the interactive prompt.

The next answer is to put an [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in `module.py`.  `__all__` should be a list of strings.  The strings should be the names of things that you want to export.  For example:

#### module.py

```
import time

__all__ = ['MyClass', 'my_func']

class MyClass():
    pass

def my_func():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing, you can use functions.  Basically, functions within functions, but you can also import inside the functions.

```
def init():
    import time
    def innerFunc():
        time.sleep(.2)
    time.sleep(.1)
    innerFunc()
init()
```

Comment: Namespaces are something a little different in python, so I'd be a little careful about using that terminology. This does work as a solution though.